# PHP - Curl is adding HTTP:// to my HTTPS URL

Tags: php, curl

Here is my code that I'm using to troubleshoot an issue with my curl connection:

```
$url = 'https://myurl.com';
$encodedurl = urlencode($url);

$token = 'my_api_key';
$postfields = 'my data';

$_h = curl_init($newurl);
curl_setopt ($_h, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authentication: Token=mytoken'));
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_URL, encodedurl);
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 );
curl_setopt ($_h, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

var_dump(curl_exec($_h));
var_dump(curl_getinfo($_h));
var_dump(curl_error($_h));
```

When I execute this, I receive this as part of the array:

```
["url"]=> string(59) "HTTP://https://myencodedurl.com/"
```

Anyone have any idea how to get rid of that HTTP:// it's adding to the beginning? I've tried str_replace at every possible place, but it seems to be happening only when curl_exec fires.

This is causing my app to fail, as the resource can't be reached...

Comment: you shouldn't encode the whole url

Comment: I know it's weird, but with the the API I'm working with, I get a 503 resource not available error unless I encode the URL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Urlencoded URL is *not* an URL anymore. It misses the protocol part, because `://` gets percent-encoded (e.g. `https%3A%2F%2Fmyurl.com`) so curl assumes and adds `http://`. But `http://https%3A%2F%2Fmyurl.com` is still not a valid URL and the request fails.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Knowing that, let me play around with it a bit and see what I can figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CURLOPT_URL` is not being set correctly. Make sure the variable you are passing it is `$encodedurl` and not `encodedurl`.

On top of that, you don't need to encode your URL. Thus, simply passing

`curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_URL, $url);`

would work just fine.

Comment: It is $encodedurl in my real code, I just messed up in the editor here.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using urlencode?

You can use:

```
$url = 'http://example.com';
```

And, as noted by @RhapX

```
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_URL, encodedurl);
```

should be

```
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Note variable name change.